# Move label in placeholder in css and html

Tags: html, css

How to Move label in placeholder in css and html.After putting data , labels shouldn't change  how is it possible ?? It's about css and html

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your code please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.